# Get the url of xml with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a button that gets the current URL, then that URL will be sought within the XML, this will return a URL1 to redirect.
What's is the problem?

[Image of XML](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/6162/codeuv.jpg)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#leerxml").click(function () {
        var urlactual = document.location.href;
        $.get("students.xml", {}, function (xml) { 
            $(xml).find("urldirige").each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("url").text() == urlactual) {
                    //do something
                    document.location.href = $(this).find("reserva").text();
                }
            }); 
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: can you explain a little more in brief. What error you facing? Give your XML response if possible with dummy values.

Comment: If your server is not returning proper `Content-Type` for your XML files then it may not work. You will need to add the `dataType` to `$.get` as in `$.get("students.xml", function(xml){ ... }, "xml")`

Comment: can you check the browser console to see if there is any errors

Comment: Change `var urlactual = document.location;` to `var urlactual = document.location.href;` and try. Because location is an object not an string

Comment: yet still does not work, help